# Is it possible to generate hair particles from a mesh base (like in xGen) / a good alternative?

Tags: particles, hair

i've been doing research on how more professional, but cartoony hair is done. for example, in the overwatch animated shorts, or in frozen

[image]
[image]

it seems that the general workflow for it is blocking it out using solid geometry and then having the hair particles calculated on top, then cleaned up pretty quickly after. the issue is with this, is it doesn't seem like it can be replicated in blender.

i have been looking at some add ons and so far i haven't been able to find any that can create hair that follows a pre-set modeled shape, or is generated from a mesh.
(please correct me if i'm wrong!)

looking it up, i found it's possible to convert particle hair from curves and grease pencil using the "HairNet" add on, but it's not exactly the best option since it's outdated and does not seem like it will be updated

**TL;DR:**
is there a possible way to generate blender particle hair from a mesh shape (even with an add on) that is up to date, or is there a better way to quickly comb a bulk of the hair to give it those stylized shapes without having to nit pick with the comb tool?

thank you for reading this!